# Conflicting lifetime requirements when using a reference inside of a closure

Tags: rust, closures

Hi I'm stuck on an issue with conflicting lifetime requirements when using a reference inside of a closure. Here is a minimal repro:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<&i32> = Vec::new();
    let x = 10;
    run(move || v.push(&x));
}

fn run<F: 'static + FnMut()>(mut f: F) {
    f();
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=22a340b1d213ba5cc2222d5469159f8e

The definition of `run` comes from a third party library so I can't change its signature (see [winit::EventLoop::run](https://docs.rs/winit/0.20.0-alpha4/winit/event_loop/struct.EventLoop.html#method.run)). Here is the error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:4:24
  |
4 |     run(move || v.push(&x));
  |                        ^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'_` as defined on the body at 4:9...
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |     run(move || v.push(&x));
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that closure can access `x`
 --> src/main.rs:4:24
  |
4 |     run(move || v.push(&x));
  |                        ^^
  = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/main.rs:4:9: 4:27]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     run(move || v.push(&x));
  |     ^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I'm having trouble understanding why accessing `x` is a problem. It looks like this code should be possible since `x` stays on the stack for the entire lifetime of the closure. Is there any way for me to reference a variable on the stack from the closure given the signature of `run`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `F: 'static` bound on `run()` means that it requires a future that either owns the data it refers to, or refers to data of static lifetime. In particular, the compiler cannot prove that the variable `x` will live until the end of the program - even though that might actually be the case for this particular program, because `x` happens to be defined near the top of `main()`.

You can't change the signature of `run()`, but if you have control over the closure and how it uses the vector, you can make it work by switching to a vector of reference-counted smart pointers instead of a vector of references:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Arc<i32>> = vec![];
    let x = Arc::new(10);
    run(move || v.push(x.clone()));
}
```

Note that the call to `clone()` doesn't actually clone `x`, it just "clones" the `Arc`, i.e. bumps the reference count. The size of `v`'s elements is unchanged (still the size of one pointer each), but each will now be separately allocated on the heap.